# What are the possible cause for EndpointNotFoundException?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4

I am trying to find the potential cause for the EndpointNotFoundException exception below (occurs on the client side, the exception is intermittent). The exception message describe two possible causes:

- No endpoint listening.
- Incorrect SOAP action.

I verified both and the endpoint is available as well as the SOAP action. The network configuration appear to be correct and all machines are up, running and under very light load. I also checked things such as proxy (there are none), concurrency (maxConcurrentConnection was increased) and performance counters (everything looks normal). Could this be caused by a bug in the client library (we are pooling proxies) where we end up with proxies in a faulted state or some socket never closed?

In brief, I’d like to know what could possibly cause that exception intermittently in a client proxy.

```
Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://production.com/MyService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 11.11.111.11:443 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) 
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 

Server stack trace: 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream() 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) 
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

Comment: I would recommend having a WCF trace generated. That often has more detailed information than the exception about what went wrong.

Comment: This is an exception happening on the client side, not the server side.

Comment: You can create traces on either side.

Comment: I am running into this same intermittent issue, did you ever figure out what was going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. In my case, **replacing the computer name by the IP worked**. I know it doesn't make much sense.

Doesn't work:

```
<endpoint address="http://MyComputerName:82/MyApplication/MyPath/MyWebService.asmx"
```

Does work:

```
<endpoint address="http://172.XX.X.X:82/MyApplication/MyPath/MyWebService.asmx"
```

I should add that the endpoint was perfectly accessible by browser using the computer name. However, when the call was made by the application, it simply didn't work.